Bicep webtest failing with ERROR: Failed to parse string as JSON
I am trying to add a webtest in bicep and while deploying I get the following error :
ERROR: Failed to parse string as JSON:
[{Id: us-tx-sn1-azr},{Id: us-ca-sjc-azr},{Id: us-il-ch1-azr},{Id: us-va-ash-azr},{Id: us-fl-mia-edge}]
Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

My bicep for this looks like :
param testLocations array
resource availabilityTest 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests@2022-06-15' = {
  name: testName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'standard'
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${appInsightsId}': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    Enabled: true
    Frequency: testFrequency
    Timeout: testTimeout
    Kind: 'standard'
    RetryEnabled: true
    Locations: testLocations
    Request: {
      RequestUrl: testURL
      HttpVerb: 'GET'
      ParseDependentRequests: false
    }
    ValidationRules: {
      ExpectedHttpStatusCode: testExpectedHttpStatusCode
      IgnoreHttpStatusCode: false
      SSLCheck: true
      SSLCertRemainingLifetimeCheck: 7
      ContentValidation: {
        ContentMatch: testExpectedContent
        IgnoreCase: true
        PassIfTextFound: true
      }
    }
    Name: testName
    SyntheticMonitorId: testName 
  } 
}

And I am passing in the locations variable like this :
[{"Id": "us-tx-sn1-azr"},{"Id": "us-ca-sjc-azr"},{"Id": "us-il-ch1-azr"},{"Id": "us-va-ash-azr"},{"Id": "us-fl-mia-edge"}]

I am guessing that the testLocations should be a string, and I have that set as an array right now. And perhaps the formatting of the locations array should be different?
Any ideas welcome!

Are you sure you're passing it like that?  According to the error message, it actually looks like this [{Id: us-tx-sn1-azr},... i.e. no double-quotes.

Have you checked the input correctly? @evolmonster


Bicep web test failing with ERROR: Failed to parse string as JSON:

In bicep, to pass the array formatted Json input you need to use '' single quotes and array declaration and definition should be done in the below format to avoid parsing errors.
param locations array = [
  {
    Id: 'us-tx-sn1-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-ca-sjc-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-il-ch1-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-va-ash-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-fl-mia-edge'
  }
]

Reference blog by @Will Velida for more related details on the availability test code.
Complete Bicep code:
param appsname string = 'examplejahapp'
param webtest string = 'sampletestj'
param location string = 'WestEurope'
param locations array = [
  {
    Id: 'us-tx-sn1-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-ca-sjc-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-il-ch1-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-va-ash-azr'
  }
  {
    Id: 'us-fl-mia-edge'
  }
]
resource Insights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' =  {
  name: 'samapsjah123'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name: appsname
}

resource availabilityTest 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests@2022-06-15' = {
  name: webtest
  location: location
  kind: 'standard'
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${Insights.id}': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    Enabled: true
    Frequency: 100
    Timeout: 60
    Kind: 'standard'
    RetryEnabled: true
    Locations: locations
    Request: {
      RequestUrl: 'https://${appService.properties.defaultHostName}'
      HttpVerb: 'GET'
      ParseDependentRequests: false
    }
    ValidationRules: {
      ExpectedHttpStatusCode: 200
      SSLCheck: true
      SSLCertRemainingLifetimeCheck: 7
    }
    Name: webtest
    SyntheticMonitorId: webtest
  } 
}

Deployment succeeded:


